# 2D advection-diffusion in a quasi 1D system

Tags: differential-equations, diffusion

I wish to solve the advection-diffusion equation for the concentration $c(x)$ at steady state inside a 2d circle, where the advection is only in one direction (along the x-axis).

The picture here below demonstrate the advection direction

[image]

I'm convinced that this problem can be narrowed down to a 1D equation

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(v c(x)+D \frac{\partial c(x)}{\partial x}\right)=0$$

where $D$ is the diffusion coefficient and $v$ is the advection velocity. The equation is equated to zero since we are looking for steady state.

The two boundary conditions should be a no flux at the boundaries (the rim), and that the total amount of the concentration is conserved $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R}c\,\mathrm{d}r\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\text{Const}$$

I ask here for assistance in writing the correct advection-diffusion for this case.

Comment: I doubt that it could be reduced to 1D since your boundary is inherently 2D.

Comment: I am not sure, you could describe the boundary through (x,y(x)) where $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$, essentially the boundary is described by one parameter, the same one describing the initial concentration. Although it might be that having a non-axisymmetric initial concentration together with a circular boundary make $c$ depend on $(x,y)$.

Comment: @Guliano, how would you write the equation, irrespective to the b.c?

Comment: no flux at the boundaries implies the conservation of the integral. The inverse logical implication doesn't hold. Anyway, if you're looking at a steady problem (no time dependence) nothing depends on time, so everything is constant. Maybe your looking for a solution with given value of the integral. Please clarify these conditions. Do you need an analytical or numerical solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your ansatz, you can match your boundary conditions. The current is (different sign from the OP, but standard if you want to interpret $v$ as a velocity):
$$
\begin{align}
j_x &= v_xc-D\partial_xc & j_y &= v_yc-D\partial_yc
\end{align}
$$
So the flux at the boundary is just the dot product with the normal vector:
$$
\phi = j\cdot n
$$
A steady state solution would satisfy:
$$
\nabla \cdot j = 0
$$
Assuming $v_y=0$, and using your ansatz so that $c$ depends only on $x$, $j_y=0$ so the equation is what you're written:
$$
\frac{dj_x}{dx} = 0
$$
i.e. $j_x$ is constant. Since there is a normal direction that is not perpendicular to $x$ (say the rightmost point of the boundary), the boundary condition (zero flux) gives:
$$
j_x = 0
$$
This is therefore just first order ODE:
$$
vc-D\frac{dc}{dx} = 0
$$
which you can solve in general if $v,D$ are spatially dependent:
$$
c = c_0\exp\left(\int_0^x\frac{v(\xi)d\xi}{D(\xi)}\right)
$$
In the case $D,v$ are constant, this simplifies to:
$$
c = c_0e^{vx/D}
$$
you only have one adjustable parameter $c_0$ (multiplicative constant from linearity). You do not have an arbitrary additive factor as well since it would violate the no flux boundary condition. Indeed, this would change the advection term of the current.

You can relate $c_0$ in terms of the total (conserved) number of particles $N$ (there is mistake in your formula of the jacobian in polar coordinates) by integrating over the whole domain. When $v,D$ are constant, this can be worked out analytically, setting $a=\frac{vR}{D}$ rescaling lengths by $R$:
$$
\begin{align}
N &= \int cd^2x \\
&= c_0R^2\int_{-1}^1 e^{-as}2\sqrt{1-s^2}ds \\
&= c_02\pi R^2 \frac{I_1(a)}{a} \\
c_0 &= \frac a{2I_1(a)}\frac N{\pi R^2}
\end{align}
$$
with $I_1$ the modified Bessel function of the first kind (courtesy of Wolfram Alpha, and corrected the error pointed out by basics).

Hope this helps.

**Answer to comments**

To build intuition, you can interpret the equation statistically as a stationary Fokker-Planck equation. You only have one equilibrium solution characterised by no net flow, given by the Boltzmann distribution. Btw, you can use this interpretation for a Monte Carlo simulation of your equations.

Even if initially the distribution starts with a transverse dependence, it will relax to a solution with only a $x$ dependence. Due to the no-flux boundary conditions, there will be a reflection of current during the transient but everything settles down in equilibrium. The transient regime would be governed by the equation:
$$
\partial_tc +\nabla\cdot j = 0
$$

The shape of the domain only matters to determine the prefactor of the equilibrium distribution. If the domain where the interior of a 3D ball, the calculation would rather give sill using $a = \frac{vR}D$ and rescaling lengths by $R$:
$$
\begin{align}
N &= \int cd^3x \\
&= c_0\pi R^3\int_{-1}^1 e^{-as}(1-s^2)ds \\
&= c_0\pi R^3 4\frac{a\cosh a-\sinh a}{a^3} \\
c_0 &= \frac{a^3}{3(a\cosh a-\sinh a)}\frac{3N}{4\pi R^3}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: It seems to me that if there is no flux at the boundary, then either the flow is reflected off or travels along the surface. In both of cases, there is certainly going to be some $y$ component of the flow which means it cannot be reduced to 1D.

Comment: That said, if the original state is the left half is filled with concentration $c_0$ and the right half with nothing, then wouldn't the steady state be $c_0/2$ (i.e., same original concentration but in twice the space)?

Comment: The advection is *initially* in the $x$ direction, but once the material collides with the curved surface then there must be a $y$ component of the velocity otherwise you're violating conservation laws.

Comment: I agree with @LPZ. The flux is the overall flux, as the sum of convection and diffusion. The "missing term" of the diffusion in $y$ direction $\partial^2  c/\partial y^2 $ should identically zero with a solution that only depends on $x$, and so it's consistent with the provided solution. Any question about time evolution is meaningless to me here. And if someone really want to study time evolution of the system, would end up with the same equation of the question, and the same solution as LPZ. Linear system has only one equilibrium, and it looks like to be LPZ solution

Comment: I was not sure to upvote yet, but I'm upvoting now after someone (anonymous as always, without any explanation) downvoted

Comment: @LPZ, thank you for the answer. I like this quasi 1D approach and the calculation is correct. I still feel something is missing, so I'm going to wait a little for another answer before accepting yours. What you suggest is quite interesting, as the geometry determines the coefficient (i.e if the shape is a rectangle and you can integrate over the area that will be the coefficient). Moreover, it seems that the functional form of the coefficient will be identical for a three dimensional shape (sphere). Do you agree with this?

Comment: if you want I could perform a Finite Element analysis to check this solution

Comment: @LPZ, thanks for your addition, it seems however that for the 3d case you have integrated over a surface, and not over a volume. is it a mistake? if not, why did you do so?

Comment: @LPZ, there are two things which are confusing in the 2D derivation: 1) you use the notation 'n' for both the boundary and the total concentration. 2) you don't show explicitly how the no flux b.c is used as the solution for the differential equation actually reads c=c_0*exp(Rv/d)+c_1 (c_1 is another coefficient which is found with the b.c )

Comment: @LPZ, also, please show, at least for the 2D case, how the integral is solved, i.e, how R^2 got outside of the integral over c(x)d^2 x

Answer (score 1):

I implemented a script to solve the problem using Finite Element Method solving the equation on the 2-dimensional domain, without any assumption.

### Correction of the small mistake made by @LPZ

The results look to agree with the intuition that the solution only depends on the $x$ coordinate, but is not the very same as the one proposed by @LPZ: in the evaluation of the constant @LPZ made a mistake, since there is a missing $2$ factor in the formula of the integral,

\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
n &= \int cd^2x \\
& =  c_0 \int_{x=-R}^{R} \int_{y=-\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}} e^{\frac{v x}{D}} dy \, dx = \\
& = c_0 \int_{x=-R}^{R} 2 \, \sqrt{R^2-x^2}e^{\frac{v x}{D}} dx = ( x = R \, s ) \\
&= \mathbf{2} \, c_0 \, R^2\int_{-1}^1 e^{as}\sqrt{1-s^2}ds \\
&= \mathbf{2} \, c_0\pi R^2 \frac{I_1(a)}{a} \\
\rightarrow \qquad c_0 &= \frac a{I_1(a)}\frac{n}{ \mathbf{2} \,\pi R^2} \ .
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

### Comparison of the analytical and numerical result (+Gist)

I'm showing you the results and share the Github Gist, https://gist.github.com/Dade1989/1f1f79247094ff09f20f19feb462b654 , with the script you can run on Colab.

Here you can find the solution, for a domain with radius $R=1$, and an equation with $D= 1.0$ and $\mathbf{v} = 0.1 \mathbf{\hat{x}}$ and value of the integral equal to $1.0$.

[image]

And this is the comparison with the solution proposed by @LPZ **corrected by the 2 factor**, shown on the side, so that it's easier to see that even the numerical solution does not depend on the coordinate $y$ even for the general 2D numerical solution, as all the node values collapse on a line (showing thus no dependence of the solution on the $y$ coordinate).

[image]

Comment: Nice work! Out of curiosity, is the offset between the simulation and the analytical solution due to discretisation (and therefore decreases with increasing resolution) ?

Comment: I produced a mesh this afternoon with **gmsh**, and I pasted and copied only the structures I needed of the .msh file at the beginning of the script. So I didn't performed any convergence study, since the "mesh import" was quite cumbersome. I (or even you, since the script is on github) could do it by splitting each triangular element of the mesh on the mid points of the sides, updating both the array of the coordinates of the nodes and the array of the connectivity (but this way, the mid points on the circle wouldn't improve the approximation of the geometry of the boundary)

Comment: I'm quite satisfied with the work done in few hours (and the minor effort to find the mistakes both in the code and the analytical formula), and quite a good comparison between the numerical solution and the analytical solution, once the factor 2 is not lost. By the agreement of the results, I'm quite confident about the script and that this is the result we were looking for, and -- more important -- the assumption of the OP was right. Being an answer on SE, I wouldn't add any more work on this subject, even without a convergence analysis of the result (on grid and degree of the approx)

Comment: Anonymous downvoting this question = LEL. This answer provides both the the correction of the analytical solution proposed by @LPZ, and a numerical solution with shared code. This forum is full of suckers.